# CYPHER recursive calculation over a subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Suppose I have a calculation that I need to perform in a child-evaluation-first fashion over a Tree-like sub-graph:

- The subgraphs are an acyclic graph
- each node has exactly one parent
- the depth is dynamic and changes over time

[image: A Tree Graph]

For each such `root` node I want to perform a quite heavy `MATCH` on its left-side subtree root (resulting in 100k-s of rows), and on its right-side subtree root, aggregate or discard results according to some of the `root` node attributes - and then propagate the results to the `root`'s `parent` -as the parent has to do the same task: evaluate the left-side child and right-side child, filter results based on `parent`'s properties and propagate upwards.

I could not find such a sequnetial\recursive functionality in `neo4j`'s syntax neither in `apoc`'s library.

for completeness, the following fashion of calculation won't help me since all paths would be executed in parallel - therefore parents would try to evaluate before children:

```
MATCH (root:Root)-[:LEFT*]->(child)
MATCH (child)-[:OtherRelations]-(...)//calc some on child 
RETURN some_combination_of_matched_on_child_and_root_node_properties
```

In addition, a `FOREACH` clause could have solved it - if I could propagate results from the current iteration to another - but `FOREACH` DOESN'T DO THAT afaik.

*Question*: How can I implement such a recursive, sequential calculation in CYPHER?

Comment: What more can you tell about the tree? E.g. is it symmetrical (all branches have the same depth)? Does every node have exactly one parent?

Comment: @Graphileon sure - it's not a symmetric tree - it's an acyclic graph (I will update). Its depth is dynamic and changes over time. Yes, every node has exactly one parent. (I was abstracting this data out)